# jquery animate function and mimic the visuallightbox like effect

Tags: jquery

EXAMPLE:
http://visuallightbox.com/lightbox-photo-software-sticky-notes-demo.html and click on any image to see how original image is showing.

I want to create the same effect with code instead of using a library.
The code that I'm using right now causes a similar effect, but it's not very smooth like visuallightbox.

Here is the code:

```
<ul>
<li>thumb</li>
<li>thumb</li>
<li>thumb</li>
<li>thumb</li>
<li>thumb</li>
<li>thumb</li>
<li>thumb</li>
<li>thumb</li>
<li>thumb</li>
</ul>
<div id="transition"><div>zoom effect<div></div>

$('ul li').click(function(e){
var $t = $('#transition'),
    to = $(this).offset(),
    td = $(document);

$t.children('div').css({width:100,height:100});
$t.css({
    top:  to.top + 50,
    left: to.left + 50,
    display: 'block'
}).animate({
    top:  td.height()/2,
    left: td.width()/2
}, 600, function(){
    $(this).animate({
        top: '-=75',
        left: '-=50'
    }, 600);
    $(this).children('div').animate({
        width:250,
        height:200
    }, 600, function(){
        // open dialog here
    });
});
});

$('#transition').click(function(e){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

How would I change this to get the desired effect?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HDmff/

Comment: you mean to say speed or graying up of the background?

Comment: wow perfect way to ask a question. much better than your previous down voted question. +1

Comment: What's wrong with your version? Seems equally smooth for me.

Comment: the effect is not like visual lightbox which i want to achieve.

Comment: @Pimgd Why did you remove the link to fiddle?

Comment: @Sang Huh? That was not what ... I did. I'm gonna go slightly off-topic here: I think there is a bug in StackOverflow which causes text below a codebox to be not loaded - that is, not in the edit code, not in my screen, no where. It's only once the suggested edit has passed that I see something disappeared...

So basically - it was not my intent to do so and it seems to happen without me knowing so. I just added "How would I change this to get the desired effect" as a question conclusion and summary. I'm now gonna check all my suggested edits: Maybe this happened a lot more than I know...

Comment: @Sang It happened http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9015586/revisions as well. I can't find any other cases... I hope it won't happen again... In case this issue gets reported somehow: I'm running 18.0.1017.2 dev Google Chrome on Ubuntu 10.10
As for the described "bug" - it seems to only occur when there is a link below the code box.